# Integral of multivariate derivative.

Tags: real-analysis, integration, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

I have yet another question about the derivative in multivariate space, which regards a notion about the integral:

$$f(x_1)-f(x_0) =  (x_1-x_0)\cdot \int^1_0 df(x_0 + t(x_1-x_0))dt$$

when:

$$[x_0,x_1] = \{ x_0 + t(x_1-x_0): 0 \leq t \leq 1\} \in U \subset \mathbb{R}^n.$$

While I do understand that the integral will of $df$ will yield $f$ (since that's its definition), I do not understand why we multiply with $(x_1-x_0)$ in the end. Could anyone help me with that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have:
$$
\frac{d}{dt} (f (x_0 + t(x_1 - x_0))) = df(x_0+t(x_1-x_0))\cdot(x_1 - x_0)
$$
by the the chain rule. Now for the left expression (!!) you can use the fundamental theorem on calculus to get your answer.